# OpenGL moving objects have a black trail

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

## Info

- OpenGL: 430
- GLFW
- glm for math
- Windows 11
- 2D
- Inspired by [LearnOpenGl Tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/)

## Problem

When i am trying to draw OpenGL "objects" ( basically a vao with a vbo ) and move them via a uniform matrix in my vertex shader for some reason red and blue objects have weird black trail.I have a video showcasing the problem [here](https://youtu.be/YrPJhnEbWWI). It is totally fine with green objects.

[Working example from last project](https://youtu.be/Ibh8H7pWjeo)

If you want to compile yourself i have a repository [here](https://github.com/DrMondGnu/OpenGlTests)

## Steps to reproduce

**Includes**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
```

**Create Window**

```cpp
GLFWwindow* window;
void init_window() {
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLFW");
        return;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); // OpenGL 4.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow((int) 1366, (int) 768, "Game", nullptr,
                              nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Failed to open GLFW window.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLFW");
        return;
    }
}
```

**Create rectangle**

```cpp
float vertices[] = {
        // Triangle 1
        -1.0f, -1.0f, // Bottom-Right
        1.0f, -1.0f, // Bottom-Left
        1.0f, 1.0f, // Top-Left
        // Triangle 2
        -1.0f, 1.0f, // Top-Right
        1.0f, 1.0f, // Top-Left
        -1.0f, -1.0f, // Bottom-Right
};

GLuint vbo;
void init_vbo() {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

GLuint vao;
void init_vao() {
    init_vbo();
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof (float), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

**Initialize shaders**

```cpp
const char* vShader = "#version 430 core\n"
                      "\n"
                      "layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertex;\n"
                      "\n"
                      "uniform mat4 model;\n"
                      "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
                      "\n"
                      "void main() {\n"
                      "    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
                      "}";
const char* fShader = "#version 430 core\n"
                      "\n"
                      "out vec4 outColor;\n"
                      "\n"
                      "uniform vec3 color;\n"
                      "\n"
                      "void main() {\n"
                      "        outColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n"
                      "}";
GLuint shader;
void init_shader() {

    GLuint vShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vShaderId, 1, &vShader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vShaderId);

    glShaderSource(fShaderId, 1, &fShader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fShaderId);

    shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader, vShaderId);
    glAttachShader(shader, fShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(shader);

    glDeleteShader(vShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(fShaderId);

    // Set projection matrix
    glUseProgram(shader);
    auto projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 1366.0f, 768.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
}
```

**Program loop**

```cpp
glm::mat4 gen_matrix(glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 size, float rotation) {
    glUseProgram(shader);
    auto model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(position, 0.0f));

    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotation), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, 0.0f));

    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(size, 1.0f));
    return model;
}

[[noreturn]] void loop() {
    glUseProgram(shader);
    // Set color
    glm::vec3 color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GLint colorPos = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "color");
    glUniform3f(colorPos, color.x, color.y, color.z);

    
    GLint modelMatPos = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model");
    glm::vec2 pos(200.0f, 200.0f);
    glm::vec2 size(40.0f, 40.0f);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    while(true) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatPos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(gen_matrix(pos, size, 0)));
        pos += 1;
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```cpp
int main()
{

    init_window();
    init_vao();
    init_shader();
    loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After looking at the video: Are you sure that you even have a problem? When you step through the video frame by frame, then each frame by itself looks fine. The "shadowing" is imho only an optical illusion due to a fast moving object.

Comment: Could be, but even so that is not desirable for a game? And in my previous engine it worked, had the same problem there

Comment: Render a sequence of frames, save the sequence as single images (lossles image format), open your favorite image editor, load the sequence of frames as layers, set the layer mode to difference. The only difference should be the shape of the sprite, do you see any vertical or horizontal lines? Compare your rendered output to a reference image (e.g. rendered in your image editor), what's the difference? Use different textures and or background colors, does this change anything?

Comment: Im not using any textures, its just a rectangle made up of vertices

Comment: Your video looks ok too me, I'd guess what you're seeing is either an artifact of your monitor or of your eyes

Comment: Ok, then use only different colors (be it for the shape or background). That doesn't change anything about the process to find out if it is a rendering artifact or an optical illusion.